# Low noise electret microphone amplifier with automatic gain control

Tags: amplifier, microphone, electret, low-noise-amplifier

I am looking for a simple solution to design a low noise electret microphone preamplifier with automatic gain control (AGC.) Generally, I need to pick up the sound from a far distance, digitalize it in a CODEC and apply a machine learning (ML) algorithm.

As a microphone, I selected [this type.](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/pui-audio-inc/AOM-5024L-HD-F-R/12152286)

It is a low noise, sensitive electret microphone. I think that this will fit into my application.

As an amplifier I already experimented with the [MAX9814.](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1713)

The first test revealed that with input noise 30nV/sqrt(Hz) the output is still quite noisy. Otherwise, the functionality is exactly what I need.

I have read other threads about  low noise preamps, but AGC was not mentioned there. I assume that AGC is a crucial part of far distance sound pick up as it can amplify weak sounds but it prevents clipping when the sound source is too close (this can not be avoided.)

Could you give me some tips for another IC or design? I prefer single supply of approximately 3VDC. I also found TS472 from ST - less noise but AGC is missing.

Comment: *I need to pick up the sound from a far distance* What distance? Do any commercial devices that can do this exist? What microphone are they using? The microphone you selected is an extremely generic one, don't expect too much from it. There is a reason why a proper directional microphone costs serious money. You can't amplify what the microphone can't pick up.

Comment: About the distance. Let's say it is a few hundred meters. The noise source produces a sound level of 95-100dB SPL (@1m). I guess that it should achievable even without special directional microphone. The microphone that I selected seems to be far better than widely used electret mics (sensitivity around -38dB, S/N around 65dBA).

Comment: *The microphone that I selected seems to be far better...* Then you have to immediately ask yourself how that microphone would achieve that. I do not see how this mic. is any better than any other cheap electret microphone. Also the price of the mic. you selected isn't much different from other similar mics. If it were that special, the manufacturer would charge a premium for it. Also, have you actually calculated the SPL at the mic.?

Comment: Maybe we are getting a little bit far from my original question about low noise amplifier. But thank you for your interest in the acoustic part as well :-) I did not calculate the exact SPL level at mic as I believe that this might be quite complex task in real environment. However, to get some rough estimation I used this tool: https://www.wkcgroup.com/tools-room/inverse-square-law-sound-calculator/  This tells me that 100dBA@1m = 50dBA@300m. Considering mic sensitivity of -24dB you can get approx. 0.4mV on microphone output (@50dbA) - still voltage that can be further processed.

Comment: I agree that the microphone you selected picks up background noises all around it because its pick up pattern is omni-directional. You need a directional mic.

Answer (score 1):

If you desire high quality then you want a sensitivity of human ears or say 0 dB and define the loudest level expected to determine the dynamic range of the AGC in decades or dB.

But the cost factors must also be in the design. Electrets being at the bottom of this scale, I would choose a moving coil microphone and low noise pre-amp. Such as one used in early reel to reel tape recorders.  Electrets are good for some things , such as open cloth backed for far field noise cancellation and adjustable directivity using a small parabolic reflector or changing the aperture size down to pick up only near-field voice next to the mic such as in mobiles.

Many AGC amps are available with 60 dB range but you may  also consider to define a spec for a compander/expander feature with a nominal initial gain and variable attack and decay time constants ,or S - curves to compress the audio as is done in professional radio and music recordings.

Therefore specific solutions depend on your specifications, as always this is your requirement.